# SpreadsheetGear Range Formula

Tags: c#, spreadsheetgear

I am using the Formula property of the Spreadsheet gear but the calculation is not coming.

Below is my code

```
"SpreadsheetGear.IRange range = WorkBookViewForData.ActiveWorksheet.Cells["E19"];
 range.Font.Name = "MS Gothic";
 range.Formula = "=SUM(E3,E18)";
 range.NumberFormat = "$#,##0_);
($#,##0);@";"
```

Is there any problem in my code. Please suggest.

Comment: @Freelancer me navin ahe yat jast kahi nmahit nahi..

Answer (score 0):

**Try following:**

```
SpreadsheetGear.IRange range = worksheet.EvaluateRange(rangeFormula);
```

**Refer:**

http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/srcview.aspx?file=spreadsheetgearimage.aspx

Here is another range formula with c# code:

http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.3.0/SpreadsheetGear~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~Formula.html